# Custom search function with result from external url

Tags: javascript, 8

I need to create a page in Drupal 8 where there is a text field and a search button.
When the user has entered a word to search and hit the search button a list with a search result should be displayed.

The search should go against this endpoint: https://example.com/api/json/1.0/searchProduct.json?query=[SEARCHWORD]
Where [SEARCHWORD] is replaced with for example **Stockholm** and results are shown.

If more than 5 results are shown a pager should show up.

Have search the internet for tips or solutions, but couldn't find anything.. Is there anyone who has a clue that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Hello since you are new to Drupal Answers I'll help you get started, but in future this type of question is way to specific and a self directed learning approach is better.

Well here we go this will get you pointed in the direction you need.

First:  you need to find out how to make a custom module (quite easy)
suggested google search "How to make Drupal 8 Module"
 -- then take you pick

-- option 1) (do it in a form with AJAX)

1.A) you need to find out how to make a form 
suggested google search "How to make Drupal 8 form"
- (read and understand) https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

1.b) in that form create a text field. called "search"

1.c) Search Google for "drupal 8 ajax form example"
 -- (read and understand) https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms

1.d) in the form ajax call back:

```
 // example 
 $url = 'http://systembevakningsagenten.se/api/json/1.0/searchProduct.json?query=';
 $term = $form_state->getValue('search');
 $query_url = $url. $term;
 $client =  \Drupal::httpClient();
 $request = $client->get($query_url);
 $data = json_decode($request->getBody(), TRUE);
 $results = [];
 if (!empty($data) && !empty($data['items'])) {
   foreach ($data['items'] as $item ) {
     $results[] = $item['name'];
   }
 }
```

at this point $results is what you want to display .. if you did step "1.c" it will be easy for you.

-- or --
Option 2 Do it in JS

2.a) Learn how and create a controller aka https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller

2.b) Learn about drupal 8 add js to controller aka read and understand 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

- Key points:
  Defining a library (your_module.libraries.yml)

  Attaching a library to page (controller) $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'your_module/library_name';

2.c) Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

2.d) once you have a controller with some custom js file attached then, 
you can use mark up from controller to create the form, and use js to make the calls and update the markup.

-- or --
Option 3) do this in a block

2.a) find out how to make a block aka Google "Drupal 8 how to make a block"

2.c) use above options to deliver the functionality you require.

And with that this will get you started ! if not point you in the correct direction of how to.